# Android : Unable to post data

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the asp.net mvc web api and posting data  from android but unable to post data

I am adding here the dummy url for some reasons.

**API Code :  this is the method to which i amsending data.**

```
public ActionResult Match(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> MatchImage)
{
```

//Code here
    }

**Android Post code**

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
            String postURL = "http://dummyurl.com/api/Match/VerifyImage";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MatchImage",imageData));

                 UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                 post.setEntity(ent);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                if (resEntity != null) {     

                System.out.println("-------------------->>>"+EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));


                }
```

**Responce :**

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://dummyurl.com/api/Match/VerifyImage'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Match'."}

Please help me..thanks

Comment: yes i  am using wrong link to post here but actualy in my code it is correct

Comment: I know, just kidding. I am not an asp.net expert, but if you google "asp.net mvc web "No type was found that matches the controller"" there are some similar questions